# Cargo claims that rustc has not json flag

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, bevy

Hi I am trying to learn the basics of rust and one of the packages(`ron`) that comes as dependency for `bevy` is throwing an error.

When I run `cargo build` I see:

> Compiling ron v0.7.0
>
> Compiling bevy_diagnostic v0.6.0
>
> Compiling bevy_gilrs v0.6.0
> Compiling bevy_winit v0.6.0 error:
>
> Unrecognized option: 'json'
>
> error: could not compile `ron`
>
> warning: build failed, waiting for
>
> other jobs to finish...
>
> error: build failed

To learn more I added `--verbose` flag, and that gave me `rustc` command that failed:

> /home/tomek/.cargo/bin/rustc --crate-name ron --edition=2018
> /home/tomek/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/ron-0.7.0/src/lib.rs
> --error-format=json --json=diagnostic-rendered-ansi,artifacts --crate-type lib --emit=dep-info,metadata,link -C embed-bitcode=no -C debuginfo=2 -C metadata=943a31496299e8f3 -C
> extra-filename=-943a31496299e8f3 --out-dir
> /storage/projects/econsim/target/debug/deps -L
> dependency=/storage/projects/econsim/target/debug/deps --extern
> base64=/storage/projects/econsim/target/debug/deps/libbase64-532e1d4e3f8b3bca.rmeta
> --extern bitflags=/storage/projects/econsim/target/debug/deps/libbitflags-c67d8a8593a87f67.rmeta
> --extern serde=/storage/projects/econsim/target/debug/deps/libserde-42ff4d97cbefd932.rmeta
> --cap-lints allow

So I put it in command line and this is the output without any error codes:

> {"artifact":"/storage/projects/econsim/target/debug/deps/ron-943a31496299e8f3.d","emit":"dep-info"}
> {"artifact":"/storage/projects/econsim/target/debug/deps/libron-943a31496299e8f3.rmeta","emit":"metadata"}
> {"artifact":"/storage/projects/econsim/target/debug/deps/libron-943a31496299e8f3.rlib","emit":"link"}

Originally I did not specify path of `rustc` for cargo to use but either way I got this error. If am not mistaken when `cargo` calls `rustc` then `--json` is no longer a valid option, but when I run `rustc` in shell its fine? I am not really sure where to proceed from here.

Comment: What does `cargo --version` and `rustc --version` output?

Comment: rustc says `rustc 1.58.0 (02072b482 2022-01-11)` and cargo `cargo 1.58.0`

Comment: Is there at least a way that I could make cargo drop that `--json` flag because it seems to me this is more of a formating option rather than something used in the actual compilation process?

Comment: `error-format=json` should probably be interpreted as "error-format is machine-readable", i.e. "Cargo can parse the errors from rustc and show them correctly".

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue.

`ron` was overriding rust-toolchain version, details are [here](https://github.com/ron-rs/ron/issues/332).

To went to location of `ron` on my hard drive and deleted `rust-toolchain` file.